# Search on hidden select2 text

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

With a standard select2 dropdown box, populated with a list of names from a database call, is there a way to search on hidden items within the search area?

Example:

Select2 box shows to end user "Charlie Watts" but actually the options value holds "Charlie Watts (22)". I want the use to be able to search for 22, but not show it by default to the end  user.

TIA

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but the options can be set to a different value than what is displayed within the list i.e. <option value='fred'>Bill Smith</option>. When this item is submitted the value of fred is sent not Bill Smith.

Comment: For clarification, the library I am using is the (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) select2 library, not a standard select box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can achieve that using the `formatResult` and/or `formatSelection` methods. There's a great example of using them in the [Select2 Docs: Templating](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#templating).

In your `format` function, filter out the " (22)" part of your value and return everything before it.

On a UX note, it could be strange to see matches appear that don't give any indication as to why they match. If that doesn't matter for your use-case, carry on.